# What is the difference between metadata generated by the ArcCatalog/ArcGIS Desktop and the tool XSLT Transform?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, metadata, xsl

When I open item description in the ArcCatalog or ArcGIS Desktop i see the following html-file:

[image: metadata formed by ArcCatalog]

This file is generated automatically, but when i want to generate this via tool **XSLT Tranformation** or via **arcpy.XSLTransform_conversion()**

I get it:

[image: metadata formed by tool]

Why there is this difference and how fix it?
I need to generate many files and I cannot manually edit each page or save each page generated by the ArcCatalog.

Comment: Did the answer match what you were looking for? if so, please accept it - thanks!!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Sorry if I incorrectly asked a question, 
I wanted to know why differs page layout of these html-files and how fix it.

Answer (score 1):

The XSLT conversion tool will use different tags for storing metadata. You would use it to *convert* existing ESRI-generated metadata to FGDC or ISO, for instance. I would be cautious about using this to *create* the metadata sheets.

As your aim is to create the metadata sheets, the tool you want to use is [SynchronizeMetadata_conversion(source, synctype)](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/conversion-toolbox/synchronize-metadata.htm). Synchronize creates the metadata sheet if absent, or updates it if present (with parameters to choose what to update and what not).

It is a ArcToolbox tool, so you can use it in Arcpy/Python scripts or directly from the GUI.